# Нужно найти среднее арифметическое чисел

Tags: python, циклы, if

Напишите программу, которая считывает с клавиатуры два числа `a` и `b`, считает и выводит на консоль среднее арифметическое всех чисел из отрезка `[a; b]`, которые кратны числу `3`.
В приведенном ниже примере среднее арифметическое считается для чисел на отрезке `[-5; 12]`. Всего чисел, делящихся на `3`, на этом отрезке 6 чисел: `-3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12−3,0,3,6,9,12`. Их среднее арифметическое равно `4.5`.
На вход программе подаются интервалы, внутри которых всегда есть хотя бы одно число, которое делится на `3`.

```
first_value = int (input("Введите первое число: "))
second_value = int (input("Введите второе число:"))
for i in range (first_value + 1,  second_value):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print (i)
```

Я написал это, нужно еще чтобы программа находила сред. арифм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

начнем с того, что написали вы её неправильно

1. у вас в данном случае диапазон `(a, b)`, т.е. `a`, `b` не входят в диапазон, а по условиям задачи должны входить

   for i in range (first_value + 1,  second_value):

т.е.

```
for i in range(first_value,  second_value + 1):
```

Теперь по среднему арифметическому - задачу можно решить несколькими способами:

**способ 1:**

ввести переменную `sum = 0` и переменную `count = 0`, для чисел кратных 3 увеличивать сумму и счётчик и по завершению цикла подсчитать среднее арифметическое

**способ 2:**

сформировать новый список из элементов, кратных 3, вычислить сумму элементов нового списка (функция `sum`) и подсчитать среднее арифметическое, используя размер нового списка

**способ 3:**

чисто математический - вычислить наименьшее число больше `a`, кратное 3 и наибольшее число, меньшее `b`, кратное 3, а дальше воспользуйтесь формулой для среднего арифметического

> Я написал это, нужно еще чтобы программа находила сред. арифм.

если вы не знаете питон от слова совсем, то сначала алгоритм придумайте словесный, что именно должно происходить и как

потом это легко будет закодить даже с почти нулевыми знаниями языка

Answer (score 0):

Где введите "С" вводим тройку и все.

```py
a = int(input('Введите число а: '))
b = int(input('Введите число b: '))
c = int(input('Введите число c: '))
numbers = [x for x in range(a, b + 1) if x % c == 0]
print('Числа которые делятся на C это: ', numbers)
average = (sum(numbers)/float((len(numbers))))
print('Среднее арифметическое этих чисел: ', average)
```